# How do I arrange an HTML/CSS grid so that elements first go in a row and then move to the next depending on page width?

Tags: html, css

[An image of what I have currently (Images here are used as placeholders; they won't be in the final product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itx0c.jpg)

(Most of the CSS code and some of the HTML code are from W3Schools, as credit.)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: in-line grid;
  gap: 25px;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.charGridButton {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.teamCharButton {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <a href="SonicAndCo/Sonic_the_Hedgehog.html">
    <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Sonic the Hedgehog
    </button></div>
  </a>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Miles "Tails" Prower
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Knuckles the Echidna
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Amy Rose
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Shadow the Hedgehog
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Rouge the Bat
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Cream the Rabbit
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Blaze the Cat
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Silver the Hedgehog
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Floee the Fox
    </button></div>

</div>
```

Not only that I want to have the buttons for Sonic, Tails, Knuckles, etc. to appear next to each other on a row in a grid, I want the number of buttons in a row to depend on the page width.

Here's how I'd put it: Current page width depicts buttons for Sonic, Tails, Knuckles, and Amy on the same row. If I zoom out, a button for Shadow is moved to the first row and the button for my soon-to-be replaced OC Floee takes its place at the last part of the second row. If I zoom in, the button for Amy is moved to the next row and the button for Silver is moved to the next row.

Comment: Please include your HTML as well, better still, provide a [MCVE]

Comment: As a side note. `button` should not be used inside an `a` tag, It is invalid HTML

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `grid-template-colums` and set it to automatically resize the children.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, auto));
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.charGridButton {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.teamCharButton {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <a href="SonicAndCo/Sonic_the_Hedgehog.html">
    <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Sonic the Hedgehog
    </button></div>
  </a>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Miles "Tails" Prower
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Knuckles the Echidna
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Amy Rose
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Shadow the Hedgehog
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Rouge the Bat
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Cream the Rabbit
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Blaze the Cat
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Silver the Hedgehog
    </button></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><button class="charGridButton teamCharButton">
      <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/sonic/images/2/2d/TSR_Sonic.png" height=75px><br/>
      Floee the Fox
    </button></div>

</div>
```